# Script to detect "empty" audio files filled with silence?

Tags: audio, batch-processing

I have a large bunch (>1000) of audio files (mp3, can be converted), where many of them are filled with unintentional silence.

I want to detect/delete all those files that contain only silence while keeping file names intact. Of course, listening through them is NOT an option.

All programming languages or solutions welcome. The simpler, the better.

This might be simple or complicated. I promise you, I did my research, but am at a dead-end.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594228/how-to-detect-a-presence-of-word-audio-silence-in-the-wav-file-using-java

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that will Trim any silence from the beginning and end of your mp3 files. You should be able to write a simple script to batch the large amount of files your looking to handle.

[dBpoweramp Music Converter (dMC)](http://www.dbpoweramp.com/dmc.htm) is free and can batch process audio files and has a DSP Effects plugin which includes:

> **Trim Silence**: remove silence from beginning or end

Comment: Thanks, that was a good idea and pointed me into the right direction! In the end, I used mp3splt instead, since it was free and rather fast, too.

Comment: BTW, the dMC you recommended was only free during the trial, I was looking into a long-term solution. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @fridde Thanks for the update and feedback. I was one of the lucky few to use it when it was free. I Should have double checked it before making the quick post. I am learning I need to double check my answers before posting.