# how to detect silence in a wav file in java

Tags: java

can someone please help me to detect silence in a WAV file using java, I've found ways to trim the file but I just want to detect silence for longer than 5sec and return an error as the file being invalid.

I have checked the Wav file and am not sure which attribute to use and how to use it to detect silence from the following

[After checking the Wav file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0jXa.png)

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594228/how-to-detect-a-presence-of-word-audio-silence-in-the-wav-file-using-java